# Runtime dynamic linker warning on Mac OS X when linking to both GameKit and StoreKit frameworks

Tags: macos, linker, warnings, gamekit, storekit

Using Mac OS X 10.8.2 and Xcode 4.5.2 if you create a new Mac OS X Cocoa application then add links to the GameKit and StoreKit frameworks you get the following warning on application startup:

```
objc[64970]: Class CKClientDispatch is implemented in both
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/CommerceKit
and
/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Versions/A/StoreKit.
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Anyone know why this happens, or how to link to these two frameworks without annoying the dynamic linker?

Comment: I never did find a way to silence this warning, and it is still present in Xcode 4.6.

Comment: I get it now at Xcode 5 and OSX sdk 10.9: "objc[8783]: Class CKClientDispatch is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommerceKit.framework/Versions/A/CommerceKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Versions/A/StoreKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."

Comment: Still present in Xcode 5.1